# How to fix: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5518: character maps to <undefined> error

Tags: python, json

I want to read a json file and then load it into a variable in Python but it keeps coming up with this error:

````
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5518: character maps to <undefined>```

My code looks like this:
with open('file.json') as f:
   loadedfile = json.load(f)


Any suggestions?? I have looked at the other answers for similar questions but they all seem to be about text files not json files.
````

Comment: I have also tried adding encoding='utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally tried to load a file which was actually a JPG.  Double-check that the file path, `file.json`, you are passing to `open` is actually a JSON file.

```
with open('file.json') as f:
   loadedfile = json.load(f)
```